# Can a function tell which module it was called from?

Tags: perl

```
package Bar;
use Foo;

sub bar { fooit "hello from bar"; }

package Foo;

sub fooit {
   # Somehow I want this function to know it was called
   # from the "Bar" module (in this case).
}
```

Preferably, this would be done without explicitly passing an argument containing the calling module's name.

Comment: You should probably explain why you want to know, as this is hardly something you can rely upon in all possible situations for most purposes.

Comment: It's for logging purposes, so I can say "fooit was called from Bar at 00:00:00".  Could you elaborate on the pitfalls here?

Comment: I often write my own little `debug` functions that work like this, so I may know where you are coming from. Usually people do not want to know what package the calling frame was compiled into, but rather its filename and line number, the way `warn` and `die` do given no newline terminator. The "pitfall", if any, is that anybody can always write `{package Other; some::function() }` and it is not as though they were in an `Other.pm` file or anything like that. Actually, they can fib the file and line, too, but I guess if you are not in some sort of hostile environment, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The builtin [`caller`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#caller) function can be used to get information about the current call stack.

```
 sub fooit {
     my ($pkg, $file, $line) = caller;
     print STDERR "fooit was called from the $pkg package, $file:$line\n";
 }
```

Comment: For a fun time, make a tied `$CALLER` variable that always contains that info. :)

Answer (score 2):

[`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) with no argument in scalar context will return the caller's namespace.

```
my $caller = caller();
```

or

```
print caller()."\n";       # '.' forces scalar context
```

or

```
print "".caller(), "\n";   # '.' forces scalar context
```

It's very rare that you need that, unless you're trying to replicate the behaviour of one of [Carp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp)'s subs.

Comment: And even if you are, there’s always `Carp::longmess`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the builtin `caller` should be the easiest and the most straightforward way to do this, but [Devel::Backtrace](http://search.cpan.org/~pepe/Devel-Backtrace-0.12/lib/Devel/Backtrace.pm) is also a worth to see CPAN module, which can provide more detail information with an elegant interface.

```perl
package Foo;
use Devel::Backtrace;

sub fooit {
    my $backtrace = Devel::Backtrace->new;

    print $backtrace->point(1)->package, "\n\n";
    print $backtrace; 
}

package Bar;

sub bar { 
    Foo::fooit('hello from bar'); 
}

package main;

Bar::bar();
```

Output:

```
Bar

Devel::Backtrace::new called from Foo (test.pl:5)
Foo::fooit called from Bar (test.pl:14)
Bar::bar called from main (test.pl:19)
```